# Count total days between current day (SQL)

Tags: sql

i'm trying to count the total days between current date and a specific column called "DayConfirm" (datetime). I want to show the total days in a new column beside the rows with "DayChanged" So far i got this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),(DayConfirm, '%m/%d/%Y') AS DAYS
FROM Administr
```

can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: there might be function in your specific DBMS

Comment: What database are you using MSSQL? Also please give details of any errors

Comment: Please add a suitable tag for your database system. Date manipulation functions seem to have the most variety between platforms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to make use of `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE() , DayConfirm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to pass Date Part ie day here attribute:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

also you missing the closing `)`; try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CURDATE(),(DayConfirm, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS DAYS
FROM Administr
```