# SQL- DATEADD and DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I have a table which has vendor_id,invoice_id,creatd_dt and total_amount. I want to split the table by the vendor id and creatd days should be less than 90 days?
how to achieve this?

Find all split invoice groups from this data set. Split invoice as:

1. invoices issued by the same vendor,
2. created within 90 days,
3. total amount of the invoices equals or exceeds $6000.

An example:

```
Invoice_ID Vendor_ID Created_Date Total_Amount
1100015001 100000108 12/03/2012 139.10
1100015002 100000108 12/03/2012 1005.80 
1100015388 100000108 28/03/2012 1802.95 
1100015507 100000108 10/04/2012 1177.00 
1100015788 100000108 04/05/2012 3187.00
```

All 5 invoices are created within 90 days, and their sum is $7311.85. Therefore, the five invoices form a split invoice group.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried so far? Please show us your attempts.

Comment: using sql server, I tried to use date diff function with min and max but it is not working.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you; show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: find all split invoice groups from this data set. Split invoice as: 1) invoices issued by the same vendor, 2) created within 90 days, and 3) total amount of the invoices equals or exceeds $6000. 

An example:
Invoice_ID Vendor_ID Created_Date Total_Amount
1100015001 100000108 12/03/2012 139.10
1100015002 100000108 12/03/2012 1005.80
1100015388 100000108 28/03/2012 1802.95
1100015507 100000108 10/04/2012 1177.00
1100015788 100000108 04/05/2012 3187.00


All 5 invoices are created within 90 days, and their sum is $7311.85. Therefore, the five invoices form a split invoice group.

Comment: that data type is `creatd_dt`?

Comment: Can you add your failing `select` query please

Comment: it is not failing, it is not giving result

Comment: Please post the query you have so far

Comment: select Invoice_ID, Vendor_ID, Created_Date ,sum(Total_Amount) as Totdal_amt from table
where total>=6000
group by Invoice_ID ,Vendor_ID, Created_Date

Comment: so you  mean `select Invoice_ID, Vendor_ID, sum(Total_Amount) as Totdal_amt from invoices group by Invoice_ID, Vendor_ID, Created_Date` ?

Comment: When you say within 'created within 90 days' are you expecting to see a row per quarter with the sum of invoices?

Comment: yes, I have posted an example in my description

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DATEDIFF() function to calculate the difference between two dates either in year, months, days, etc. And to get the current date, you can do that with GETDATE() function. learn more about it at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Comment: You can also check answers to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652987/count-total-days-between-current-day-sql

Comment: w3f**ls is a poor reference, too many errors at that place.